# Installing mod_perl-2.0.8 on Apache httpd-2.4.9

Tags: apache, perl, mod-perl

I need to install mod_perl 2.0.8 in linux redhat operating system with apache-2.4.9. I have successfully installed "apache-2.4.9", but while installing mod_perl 2.0.8, Makefile.PL executed successfully and when executing make command it throws the below error. can any one help me to resolve this error.

```
perl Makefile.PL MP_APXS=/install/others/apache2/bin/apxs MP_APR_CONFIG=/install/others/httpd-2.4.9/srclib/apr/apr-1-config PREFIX=/install/others
[warning] mod_perl dso library will be built as mod_perl.so
[warning] You'll need to add the following to httpd.conf:
[warning] 
[warning]   LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so
[warning] 
[warning] depending on your build, mod_perl might not live in
[warning] the modules/ directory.

[warning] Check the results of
[warning] 
[warning]   $ /install/others/apache2/bin/apxs -q LIBEXECDIR
[warning] 
[warning] and adjust the LoadModule directive accordingly.
```

But when executing make command it throws the below error

```
make
cd "src/modules/perl" && make
...
...
cp Connection.pm ../../../blib/lib/Apache2/Connection.pm
/usr/bin/perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap /install/others/mod_perl-2.0.8/xs/typemap  Connection.xs > Connection.xsc && mv Connection.xsc Connection.c
gcc -c  -I/install/others/mod_perl-2.0.8/src/modules/perl -I/install/others/mod_perl-2.0.8/xs -I/install/others/httpd-2.4.9/srclib/apr/include -I/install/others/apache2/include -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/include/gdbm -DMOD_PERL -DMP_COMPAT_1X -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic   -DVERSION=\"2.000008\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.000008\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"  -DMP_HAVE_APR_LIBS Connection.c
Connection.xs: In function âXS_Apache2__Connection_remote_addrâ:
Connection.xs:117: error: âconn_recâ has no member named âremote_addrâ
Connection.xs: In function âXS_Apache2__Connection_remote_ipâ:
Connection.xs:134: error: âconn_recâ has no member named âremote_ipâ
Connection.xs:138: error: âconn_recâ has no member named âremote_ipâ
make[3]: *** [Connection.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/install/others/mod_perl-2.0.8/WrapXS/Apache2/Connection'
make[2]: *** [subdirs] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/install/others/mod_perl-2.0.8/WrapXS/Apache2'
make[1]: *** [subdirs] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/install/others/mod_perl-2.0.8/WrapXS'
make: *** [subdirs] Error 2
dqmadmin@weblp0005:/install/others/mod_perl-2.0.8
```

Thanks,
Shanmugam A.

Answer (score 1):

From http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/perl-dev/201206.mbox/%3C4FCD5101.4060206@PCCC.com%3E

```
Connection.xs: In function 'XS_Apache2__Connection_remote_addr':
...
```

To fix those, I edited apache2_structures.map & StructureTable.pm to change remote_addr and remote_ip to client_addr and client_ip

Also

```
ServerRec.xs: In function 'XS_Apache2__ServerRec_loglevel':
...
```

To fix that, I changed the /xs/tables/current/Apache2/StructureTable.pm to point to log.level instead of loglevel.